# Acer Travelmate P253-M Freezes on BIOS

Tags: laptop, boot, bios

I was trying to create a dual boot of Windows 8 and Ubuntu. I successfully installed Ubuntu on the hard disk but it wasn't able to boot so I went through boot-repair which said that I should put a certain file as EFI. I did that, restarted and only Acer logo appeared with nothing else. F2 didn't work, I couldn't get to BIOS any other way.

What I have tried:

- Re-seat the RAM
- Trying to boot with other hard drives
- Trying to boot from flash drive
- Trying to boot from CD
  (and all possible combinations with these three)
- Downloaded BIOS update from the Acer website (http://www.acer.co.uk/ac/en/GB/content/drivers), but it only has a version to flash from within Windows (.exe file, but I can't boot to Windows or anything else at all)
- Shorted JCMOS1 jumper for 20 seconds after which the ACER logo disapeared and instead:

  - After I press the power key, a completely black screen appears for about 5 seconds. After that the backlight on the monitor turns on and the message "Press  to enter Setup." appears on the very bottom. Pressing F2 does nothing.
  - If I hold Fn+Esc and then power up, system info appears (Insyde H2O EFI 3.7, Copyright... System BIOS version: v2.13, Processor type etc.) on top and the "Press F2 to enter Setup." on the bottom.

    - Pressing F2 removes the bottom message and scrolls one line up but nothing else.
    - Pressing Alt+F10 removes the bottom message, scrolls about 4 lines but nothing else.
- I opened the laptop completely, removed the CMOS battery for about an hour, shorted the JCMOS1 pin once again, put it back - nothing.

Any ideas are very welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: I would contact Acer on what the proper procedure to resolve this problem is exactly.